# List files in same directory using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to list files in a folder.  I have done this before, so I am not sure why I am having a problem now.

I have a PDF files I am trying to display to my web page.  The directory structure looks like this:

```
folder1/folder2/displayFiles.php
folder1/folder2/files.pdf
```

displayFiles.php is the process file where I am using the code below.

I am trying to display the file called files.pdf onto the page, which is in the same directory as the process file.

Here is my code so far:

```
 <?php
   $dir = "folder1/folder2/"; 
   // $dir = "/";  <-- I also tried this
   $ffs = scandir($dir);

   foreach($ffs as $ff)
   {
     if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..')
     {
       $filesize = filesize($dir . '/' . $ff);  
       echo "<ul><li><a download href='$dir/$ff'>$ff</a></li></ul>";
     }
   }
 ?>
```

I know it's a simple fix.  I just cannot find the code to fix it.

Comment: Change the dir to point to the folder correctly `$dir = ".";`

Comment: @RiggsFolly - This is exactly what I needed to fix this.  I knew it was a simple fix.  If you create an answer below, I will accept it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$dir` is pointing at a non-existent folder

Change the dir to point to the folder correctly `$dir = ".";`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `glob`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.glob.php

```
$pdfs = glob("*.pdf"); // if needed loop through your directorys and glob files
print_r($pdfs);
```

Just an example. You should be able to use it with some edits.

Comment: thank you, sir.  I was able to use the method @RiggsFolly suggested above.